# ArgumentError when passing ctypes array to C function

Tags: python-3.x, wrapper, ctypes

I'm trying to use a C function `copyDataContent` that copies float data from a C struct object I point to with pointer `DataHandle` into a location given by a float pointer. I have included the function prototype for this function. I can get the dimensions of this data via another function in the library. My code is below.

Prototype of `copyDataContent`

`void copyDataContent(DataHandle DataSource, float* Destination);`

Here's where things go wrong:

```
data = createData()
size0 = getDataPropertyInt(data,0)
size1 = getDataPropertyInt(data,1)
arrC = C.POINTER(C.c_float*size0*size1)
libc.copyDataContent.argtypes = [DataHandle,C.POINTER(C.c_float)]
libc.copyDataContent(data,arrC)
```

Console output:

```
ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_float instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType
```

^from the line where I actually call copyDataContent

But here's what the console tells me about `arrC`

```
arrC
Out[88]: __main__.LP_c_float_Array_0_Array_0
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is going wrong? ctypes docs aren't helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrC = C.POINTER(C.c_float*size0*size1)` creates a *type* not an instance.

If you want the instance of an array, use `arrC = (C.c_float*size0*size1)()`.

to pass it to a `float*` parameter, use `libc.copyDataContent(data,cast(arrC,POINTER(c_float)))`.

Comment: Thank you, this sorted things out